# how we can add two event listeners click and keydown in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use click and keydown together but having a problem by pressing key. Is it possible that if we can join both events in one statement.

HTML

```
 <audio id="Q" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3"> </audio>
 <div>
      <button name="Q">Q</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
    const queButton = document.querySelector("[name=Q]");
    queButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
            document.getElementById("Q").play();
    });    

    queButton.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
            if (e.key == 81) {
                document.getElementById("Q").play();
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because audio playback only occurs when a specific key is pressed, it's not possible to share the entire event handler between both the `click` and `keydown` events.

It is however possible to define a reusable function (ie `playSoundQ()`) that is called for both events as shown below:

```js
/* Define reusable play sound function for both events */
function playSoundQ() {
  document.getElementById("Q").play();
}

const qButton = document.querySelector("[name=Q]");
/* It's possible to pass the playSoundQ directly as the event handler
here, seeing there's no additional logic in the event handler */
qButton.addEventListener("click", playSoundQ);

/* Add keydown event listener to document rather than button */
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {

  /* Change to keyCode */
  if (e.keyCode == 81) {
    playSoundQ();
  }
});
```

```html
<audio id="Q" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3"></audio>
<div>
  <button name="Q">Q</button>
</div>
```

Note also that a few fixes have been applied here; the `keydown` listener is added to the `document` rather than the `button` to ensure key based playback is reponsive to all key events that occur in the browser. The `e.key` in your `keydown` handler has also been corrected to `e.keyCode` to ensure that playback happens when the "Q" key is pressed.

Hope that helps!

Comment: @user6642297 please consider accepting the answer if it has been helpful by clicking the grey tick next to the answer